# My helpful flag count seems to be stuck at 80

Tags: support, flags, flag-history, helpful-flags

On July 20th I earned the "Deputy" flag for hitting my 80th helpful flag. Slow clap, anyone? :-)

Since then, no new flags show up on my flag summary (helpful, declined, or not yet addressed). I know I've flagged at least a handful of answers, and I know at least two of them have been deleted by different moderators. It's quite possible that the moderators deleted these answers and didn't find my flag helpful, or someone else flagged them first, but the fact that I've flagged them should show up regardless of the outcome.

So I'm wondering if it's by design that once I hit 80 my flag summary seems to have become locked?

I don't really care about the number, it would just be nice to see the flags as they are addressed. Right now I'm running blind on all new flags, so while I can try to remember them and go back to check what has happened, being both lazy and forgetful works against me. :-)

**EDIT**

For the benefit of the devs, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612303/sql-server-variable-loose-its-value-in-stored-procedure/11612511#11612511) earlier today, and it seemed to have led to the post being deleted by a mod. But the flag does not show up on my flagging summary. A flag I've added since then (to help @BilltheWizard find me in the dashboard) *has* shown up on my flagging summary, so this seems to be a transient problem and I don't believe it is browser-related (I have been using the same browser for several weeks).

And again, I don't care that a single flag went missing. Just trying to determine if this is a systemic problem, and alert the devs if so. I posted here in case I'm not the only one who has seen this.

Comment: @Bo I know how to click the number, but on that page no new flags are showing up in the summary (the most recent one is from July 20, and I know I've had some since then), and the flagging history on the right shows that "helpful" adds up to 80. These numbers haven't changed since I hit 80. But like I said, I've flagged more answers since then, and they're not listed even though they seem to have been dealt with. Even if they were declined, they should still be making it onto my summary.

Comment: If your flag submitted, it should always appear in your flagging history forever and ever. Only the devs can really debug this for you since it's not visible to us mortals. But I have over 1,300 flags in my history, so it doesn't "stop" there. Are you sure you actually flagged the posts and the orange popup wasn't a "You're out of flags" message?

Comment: @animuson yes, I'm 100% positive I flagged the posts, and I'm 100% positive I wasn't out of flags. Also I realize that only devs can look into it for me, but it might be something that happens now as users hit 80 helpful flags, that wasn't a problem when you hit 80 helpful flags. So possibly someone else has seen this and can confirm.

Comment: Did you start using a new (unsupported, beta) browser around the time you hit 80 helpful flags?  Perhaps there is some kind if `POST` error happening where your flags aren't really making it.  (Just a crazy, random thought here)

Comment: Nope, have been using Chrome for a couple of months now. And a flag I created today on dba.stackexchange.com was dealt with, shows in my summary, and was marked as helpful. I know it's not proving anything but the basic mechanics should be the same across the SE network.

Comment: Flags are automatically marked helpful when we delete posts, so we don't have to manually mark the vast majority of flags.  All of them should be helpful, declined, or disputed.  Can you flag a few things to test on?  I can't find you anywhere in the dashboard.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I flagged an answer and that showed up on my flagging summary now. Let me find an answer I know I flagged over the weekend that doesn't show up. Once you find me in the dashboard, can you find the previous flag you see from me, or is that all obliterated?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I flagged [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612303/sql-server-variable-loose-its-value-in-stored-procedure/11612511#11612511) and Brad Larson deleted the answer, but the flag doesn't show up on my summary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can only see flags that are currently waiting to be processed in the dashboard.  All of your handled flags are accessible through your user page (I know you know this, but moderators can see them as well).  If your flags don't show up in either of those two places, a dev will have to look into this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're not listed in the flag history of the answer deleted by Brad.  I do see the new flag you raised though.

Comment: @BilltheLizard can you confirm that at least one other person flagged it as not an answer? I am 100% certain I did so, but maybe if I wasn't the only one there was some circumstance that led to my flag being swept away somehow.

Comment: Note: I think @BilltheLizard should definitely change his display name to "Bill the Wizard" =P

Comment: @jadarnel27 I was thinking the same thing, every time I tried to type it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, one other person did flag that post as not an answer.  In other news, the system recorded your other flag as helpful, so at least your not totally stuck.

Comment: @BilltheLizard thanks for confirmation. Is there any documented behavior about what happens when multiple people flag the same answer? In this case I'm happy enough knowing that the question was flagged and dealt with correctly, I'd just like to understand what might lead to a flag becoming a no-op.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nothing different should happen.  It's really common for multiple people to flag the same post.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Maybe just on Meta. :)